# Пройтись циклом XSL по не вложенной структуре XML

Tags: php, xml, xslt

Как поочередно вывести такой набор тегов через цикл? ТеговТегов может быть не ограниченное количество. XML:

```
<tagName ROWNUM="1">Олег</tagName>
<tagName ROWNUM="2">Виктор</tagName>
<tagName ROWNUM="3">Денис</tagName>
<tagName ROWNUM="4">Кирилл</tagName>
<tagSecName ROWNUM="1">Олегович</tagSecName>
<tagSecName ROWNUM="2">Викторович</tagSecName>
<tagSecName ROWNUM="3">Денисович3</tagSecName>
<tagSecName ROWNUM="4">Кириллович</tagSecName>
```

Чтоб было "Олег Олегович, Виктор Викторович, Денис Денисович"...?
Раньше была вложенная структура и разбирал через for-each. Теперь признак группы в ROWNUM

Comment: А какой xml на входе? Или нужно просто сгенерировать такие узлы?

Comment: Это и есть xml на входе. Его нужно пройти циклом и вывести поочередно все группы.

Comment: Исправил структуру, думаю, так будет понятнее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XSLT 1.0. Три варианта.

1. Дважды используется `following-sibling`, что некрасиво и непроизводительно.

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="//tag[@ROWNUM = following-sibling::tag/@ROWNUM]">
       <name>
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           <xsl:variable name="rownum" select="@ROWNUM"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::tag[@ROWNUM = $rownum]"/>
       </name>
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```
2. Используем ключ. И два цикла, что тоже неизящно.

   ```
   <xsl:key name="num" match="tag" use="@ROWNUM"/>


   <xsl:for-each select="//tag[@ROWNUM = following-sibling::tag/@ROWNUM]/@ROWNUM">
       <name>
           <xsl:for-each select="key('num', .)">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           </xsl:for-each>
       </name>
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```
3. Опять используем ключ. Вместо второго цикла используем доступ по индексу.

   ```
   <xsl:key name="num" match="tag" use="@ROWNUM"/>


   <xsl:for-each select="//tag[@ROWNUM = following-sibling::tag/@ROWNUM]/@ROWNUM">
       <name>
           <xsl:value-of select="key('num', .)[1]"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="key('num', .)[2]"/>
       </name>
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```

---

С разными именами групп тегов ничуть не сложнее.

1. Простой вариант.

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="//tagName/@ROWNUM">
       <name>
           <xsl:variable name="num" select="."/>
           <xsl:value-of select="//tagName[@ROWNUM = $num]"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="//tagSecName[@ROWNUM = $num]"/>
       </name>
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```
2. Вариант с ключами. При большом количестве элементов, вероятно, будет быстрее.

   ```
   <xsl:key name="num" match="tagName" use="@ROWNUM"/>
   <xsl:key name="secnum" match="tagSecName" use="@ROWNUM"/>


   <xsl:for-each select="//tagName/@ROWNUM">
     <name>
       <xsl:value-of select="key('num', .)"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="key('secnum', .)"/>
     </name>
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```

Comment: Забыл указать важную деталь - у тегов есть соответствующие имена - исправил в структуре. (<tagName> <tagSecName>). Возможно, это облегчит задачу?

Comment: @ОлегГригорьев - см. обновление.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо! Не было времени углубиться в XSL - очень выручили.

Answer (score 1):

Задача простая

```
 <?php
    $xml = '
    <root>
    <tag ROWNUM="1">Олег</tag>
    <tag ROWNUM="2">Виктор</tag>
    <tag ROWNUM="3">Денис</tag>
    <tag ROWNUM="4">Кирилл</tag>
    <tag ROWNUM="1">Олегович</tag>
    <tag ROWNUM="2">Викторович</tag>
    <tag ROWNUM="3">Денисович3</tag>
    <tag ROWNUM="4">Кириллович</tag>
    </root>
    ';

    $xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $findingRownum = array();
    $stringResult = '';
    // перебираем все элемены под ряд
    foreach($xmlObject as $_node) {
      // получае rownum
      $idRow = (string)$_node['ROWNUM'];
      // проверяем был ли он обработан
      if(array_search($idRow,$findingRownum) !== false) {
        continue;
      }
      // записываем idRow в масив обработанных
      $findingRownum[] = $idRow;
      // получаем элементы по ROWNUM
      $elementsIds = $xmlObject->xpath("tag[@ROWNUM='$idRow']");
      // перебираем их и конкретинируем
      foreach($elementsIds as $_elements) {
        $stringResult .= $_elements .'-';
      }
      // логика представления
      $stringResult = trim($stringResult,'-');
      $stringResult .= "\n";
    }

    echo $stringResult;
```

ну собственно всё

Comment: Мне бы без пхп, на чистом XSL...

Comment: @ОлегГригорьев зачем тэг php тогда поставили?

Comment: Чтоб в КРАЙНЕМ случае можно было решить через пхп, но мне дали хороший вариант на xsl. Вам тоже большое спасибо!